# Is tawbah for same-sex Zina possible?

Tags: tawba, zina

*Assalamualaikum!
I want to share my situation about Zina and I really want to make Tawbah because I'm really ashamed of of what I've done as it one of the greatest sin a Muslim could commit. I really want to repent for those sins and to never do it again.*

I had committed multiple zina with the same sex, is tawbah possible and would it be accepted by Allah?

And if yes, how do I perform Tawbah?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! Allah is most forgiving and merciful did you hear the Hadith?

Abu Huraira reported: The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “A prostitute had once been forgiven. She passed by a dog panting near a well. Thirst had nearly killed him, so she took off her sock, tied it to her veil, and drew up some water. Allah forgave her for that.”

Source: Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 3143, Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 2245

So yes Allah will forgive sins EVEN ZINA and losing hope in Allah’s forgiveness and help is a major sin also so how do you perform tawbah?

1. Admit your sin to Allah
2. Feel regret feel remorse be sincere
3. If you you can undo it then undo it for example (stealing)
4. Promise Allah never to do it again
   If all these four things are there Insha’Allah Allah will forgive you. Do not lose hope please Allah is always merciful to his slaves.